# When a new row inserted into a database I want to load a webpage of our all client

Tags: php, jquery

Without using ***set interval*** function of JQuery is there any way that when a new user registered from front-end then our user list page of admin panel automatically reloaded.

Comment: Sounds like websockets would be a better idea.

Comment: Tagged php, but I'd use SignalR if you're not restricted to server-side tech - which uses whatever is available on the client/server, including both websockets and polling if websockets not available, but wraps it all up for you with automatic fallback.

Comment: Take a look at https://pusher.com/, think that can help you :)

Comment: Question title is "when row inserted in db", but question is "when new user registered from front-end" - these are very different requirements.

Comment: Like push notification I need to push a url to our client.

Comment: when a new row inserted on user table I want reload or refresh user listing page of all our admin.

Comment: Now I am doing it using JQuery set interval function. In every 10 second its check new row inserted or not then it refresh the listing page.But Problem is it increase our server load. So I want 
when a new row inserted on user table I want reload or refresh user listing page of all our admin.

Comment: @DebojyotiChakraborty Do you really have so many new registrations in such a short time that you really need this function? Do your admins really need a live update of every single registration? Ask you those questions.

Comment: "it increases our server load". How many registrations are happening? how often do you need to check in reality (e.g. what will the admins do with this info at such short intervals)? And how many people have got the page open? If it's only 1 or 2 people then the server load will really not increase problematically, unless you have a very old/slow server, or it's already overloaded with other tasks.

Comment: Yes @Twinfriends site registration is open everyday for 2 hours and in every 15 second a new registration is done. Admin want to reload the page automatically only when a new registration done.

Comment: Okay. So I think your admin has to so something with this new registrated people? Otherwise it wont make sende that you reload the page. But yes, I think websocket would be something you're looking for.

Comment: @Twinfriends yes you are right. Is there any way to use websocket in php and Jquery

Comment: For sure. You can imagine websocket as a new protocol. Right now, your client is sending requests to the server, the server answers, that was it. With websocket the server can push data to the client without having them to asking for. May take a look at http://socketo.me/